# Windows screenshot not properly working with triple monitors (two landscape and one vertical modes)

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, screenshot

[Situation]

I have triple monitors, two LG-24MK400H monitors and one LG-24MB35 monitor.
LG-24MK400H monitors are in landscape mode, LG-24MB35 is in vertical (pivot) mode.
All three monitors are connected to my GTX1050Ti graphics card.

LG-24MK400H ----- ( HDMI Cable) ----- GTX1050Ti HDMI Port
LG-24MK400H ----- ( DP Cable  ) ----- GTX1050Ti DP Port
LG-24MB35   ----- ( DVI Cable ) ----- GTX1050Ti DVI Port

GPU driver and each monitor driver are all installed and up-to-date.

[Problem]

When I try to take a screenshot, either by using pressing "Windows key-Shift-S" or by using a 3rd party screenshot tool, the first and second screens are moved roughly halfway to the right, as if something is pushing the screen to the right.

[image: Problem example]

I've figured out that the pivotted monitor (screen 3) is the problem-maker. When I put all three monitors on landscape mode, no screenshot disruption occurs. However, when the screen 3 is put on pivot (vertical) mode, screen 1 and 2 are pushed to the right when taking screenshots.

Somebody shed some lights on this and me.

Thank you.

Comment: Please upload your example images to the Superuser-provided image host. I am not comfortable clicking a link to an unrecognized or untrusted host.

Comment: Sorry but it says i lack reputation score to post images.

Comment: @Dongsan fixed the image for ya - forgot about the rep limit on images.

Comment: @Karu Thank you very much.

Comment: I somehow made a work-around for this. The solution was to re-arrange the sequence of the screens, from 3 1 2 to 1 2 3, by changing the cables for each monitor to the graphics card. Anyways, this is not a perfect solution since I had to move my computer to an unwanted position due to the different and limited length of the cables.

Comment: You can still link an image using the provided tool. Someone with enough rep can edit your comment and inline the image.